# Multiple data values in AJAX from different sources

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this bit of Jquery which passes a value via AJAX to another page to add to a query from a drop down box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('select[name="door_size"]').change(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'functions/process.php',
            type:'get',
            data:{'value' : $(this).val()}, 
            dataType:"html",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#sub").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works perfeclty fine but I need to pass another piece of data from a GET earlier on in the code which has nothing to do with the drop down box. So I tried adding:

```
data:{'value' : $(this).val(), 'door' : <?php echo $door_model ;?>},
```

To the data line, but this just results in Firebug telling me that the value of whatever the GET was is not defined.

How can I resolve this and what is causing it?

Comment: did you try `'door' : '<?php echo $door_model ;?>'}...`

Comment: @Johnny000 ARGH! I wasn't aware that that was what was needed. Is this because it's acting as a sort of 'static' value rather than using (this)? If you could please post this below I will accept this answer.

Comment: yes it's a static value, since it's just a php echo. You always need to enclose the echo inside quotes then. :) $(this).val() is already in the right format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose your output inside quotes too:

```
'door' : '<?php echo $door_model ;?>'
```

Also; you don't need to enclose `door` inside quotes:

```
door : '<?php echo $door_model ;?>'
```

would work too.